# Webpack Externals Causing Crashing Tests

Tags: reactjs, phantomjs, webpack, karma-jasmine

After seeing a huge deployment bundle in my react project I decided to define externals to cut down on the size in the webpack.config.js file.

```
 'react': 'React',
 'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
 'react-router': 'ReactRouter', ...
```

Now the bundle is very small and the site works fine but when I try to run my tests (karma/jasmine) I get a strange error in the terminal:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ReactRouter
```

This is obviously from the externals but I'm not used to defining these in the webpack. Does anyone know if these references need to be defined somewhere else too? webpackConfig is already being pulled into the karma config.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still using `require("react-router")` in your code? webpack externals allow you to `require` the thing on the left, and webpack will just look on `window[thing on the right]` to find it — so in this case, `require("react-router")` will return `window.ReactRouter`.

Comment: I am still using require("react-router")...etc. Interestingly, the site runs but the test suite crashes. If I try window.ReactRouter it is not defined.